# Find Intervals with Most Overlaps

Tags: java, beginner, algorithm

Given a list of time intervals, I want to return the intervals with the most overlaps (i.e. most people free). My solution runs in \$O(n \log n)\$, but I made a bunch of "tracker" variables. How can I avoid creating all these variables?

`Interval` class:

```
public class Interval {
    int start;
    int finish;

    public Interval(int start, int finish) {
        this.start = start;
        this.finish = finish;
    }
}
```

`Point` class (used in my algorithm):

```
public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {
    int time;
    TimeType type;

    public Point(int time, TimeType type) {
        this.time = time;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int compareTo(Point p) {
        if (time == p.time) {
            if (!type.equals(p.type)) {
                if (type == TimeType.Finish) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        return time - p.time;
    }
}
```

`TimeType` enum:

```
public enum TimeType {
    Start, Finish
}
```

The method that returns overlapping intervals:

```
public List<Interval> getOverlappingIntervals(List<Interval> intervals) {
        List<Point> sortedTimes = new ArrayList<Point>();
        Map<Point, Interval> map = new HashMap<Point, Interval>();
        Map<Point, Point> pointMap = new HashMap<Point, Point>();
        List<Interval> res = new ArrayList<Interval>();
        List<Point> currPartial = new LinkedList<Point>();
        List<Point> bestPartial = new LinkedList<Point>();
        int overallBest = 0;
        int currBest = 0;

        for (Interval i : intervals) {
            Point startPoint = new Point(i.start, TimeType.Start);
            Point endPoint = new Point(i.finish, TimeType.Finish);
            sortedTimes.add(startPoint);
            sortedTimes.add(endPoint);
            map.put(startPoint, i);
            pointMap.put(endPoint, startPoint);
        }

        Collections.sort(sortedTimes);

        for (int i = 0; i < sortedTimes.size(); i++) {
            Point curr = sortedTimes.get(i);
            if (curr.type.equals(TimeType.Start)) {
                currBest++;
                currPartial.add(sortedTimes.get(i));
            } else {
                currBest--;
                if (currBest == 0) {
                    currPartial.clear();
                } else {
                    currPartial.remove(pointMap.get(sortedTimes.get(i)));
                }
            }
            if (currBest > overallBest) {
                overallBest = currBest;
                bestPartial = new LinkedList<Point>(currPartial);
            }
        }

        for (Point p : bestPartial) {
            res.add(map.get(p));
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Is it really \$O(n\log n)\$?

Inside your main loop, you have this line:

```
            currPartial.remove(pointMap.get(sortedTimes.get(i)));
```

which removes a `Point` object from a linked list.  This takes \$O(n)\$ time, so your whole algorithm takes \$O(n^2)\$ time.

Not only that, but this line which copies the best list so far is also \$O(n)\$ time:

```
           bestPartial = new LinkedList<Point>(currPartial);
```

#### Possible fixes

You could fix the first problem by using a data structure other than a `LinkedList`.  For example, you could use a `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet`.

You could fix the second problem by not making a copy of the best solution.  Instead, remember the index `i` of the best solution.  Then when you want to print the best solution, make another pass through the sorted times doing exactly what the first pass did.  This time, however, you stop at the best index and print the contents of `currPartial` at that index.

Comment: I'm confused about how to remember the index of the best solution. Do you mean keeping the indices of the best intervals? I don't see how I can do that without making O(n) either as well though.

Comment: @fluffychaos `bestIndex = i` where you currently have `bestPartial = ...`

Answer (score 4):

#### Beware overly common names

> ```
> public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {
> ```

Consider changing this to something else, e.g.

```
public class IntervalBoundary implements Comparable<IntervalBoundary> {
```

`Point` is already heavily used as a name for points in space.  For example, Java's Abstract Window Toolkit (AWT) has a `Point` class and is heavily used in Java graphical user interfaces (GUIs).

Also consider making this a [nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).  Then it wouldn't conflict if you used `Interval` and some other type of `Point` in the same application.

#### All `enum` implement `Comparable`

> ```
>             if (!type.equals(p.type)) {
>                 if (type == TimeType.Finish) {
>                     return -1;
>                 }
>                 return 1;
>             }
>             return 0;
> ```

[`Java.lang.Enum`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/java_lang_enum.htm) implements `Comparable` (and `Serializable` but that doesn't matter now).  So you can just say

```
            return type.compareTo(p.type);
```

#### Use your helper class

> ```
>         List<Point> sortedTimes = new ArrayList<Point>();
>         Map<Point, Interval> map = new HashMap<Point, Interval>();
>         Map<Point, Point> pointMap = new HashMap<Point, Point>();
> ```

You create three parallel data structures working with your helper class.  You could get this down to just

```
        List<Point> sortedTimes = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

if you change `Point` to know what its opposite point is and to what interval it belongs

```
    private class Boundary implements Comparable<Boundary> {
        int time;
        TimeType type;
        Interval interval;
        Boundary opposite;

        public Boundary(int time, TimeType type, Interval interval) {
            this.time = time;
            this.type = type;
            this.interval = interval;
        }

        public Boundary(int time, TimeType type, Interval interval, Boundary start) {
            this(time, type, interval);
            this.opposite = start;
        }

        public void setOpposite(Boundary opposite) {
            this.opposite = opposite;
        }

        public Boundary getOpposite() {
            return opposite;
        }

        public Interval getInterval() {
            return interval;
        }

        public int compareTo(Boundary p) {
            if (time == p.time) {
                if (type == p.type) {
                    if (opposite.time == p.opposite.time) {
                        return opposite.type.compareTo(p.opposite.type);
                    }

                    return Integer.compare(opposite.time, p.opposite.time);
                }

                return type.compareTo(p.type);
            }

            return Integer.compare(time, p.time);
        }
    }
```

Then you don't need the extra data structures.

I also changed the name to `Boundary` as causing fewer name conflicts.  I decided that was sufficient since I nested it inside another class.

#### Collections know their size

> ```
>             if (curr.type.equals(TimeType.Start)) {
>                 currBest++;
>                 currPartial.add(sortedTimes.get(i));
>             } else {
>                 currBest--;
>                 if (currBest == 0) {
>                     currPartial.clear();
>                 } else {
>                     currPartial.remove(pointMap.get(sortedTimes.get(i)));
>                 }
>             }
>             if (currBest > overallBest) {
>                 overallBest = currBest;
>                 bestPartial = new LinkedList<Point>(currPartial);
>             }
> ```

So `currBest` is 0 when `currPartial` is empty.  It increases when you add to `currPartial`.  It decreases when you remove from `currPartial`.  In fact, it is just the size of `currPartial`.  So just say that.

```
            if (curr.type.equals(TimeType.Start)) {
                currPartial.add(sortedTimes.get(i));
            } else {
                currPartial.remove(pointMap.get(sortedTimes.get(i)));
            }

            if (currPartial.size() > bestPartial.size()) {
                bestPartial = new LinkedList<Point>(currPartial);
            }
```

Now you don't have to maintain two of the extra variables.